# Typescript type separation

Tags: typescript, database, types

I would like to know if the following logic is correct.

in typescript you can create 2 or more types for the same set of data?

For example is  correct to define a WritePost type
`Type WritePost = { title: string, description: string }`
that I will use to write to the db and a ReadPost type
`Type WritePost = { id: number, createdAt: Date, title: string, description: string }`
that I will use to read from the db?

Answer (score 1):

Better then creating two completely separated types would be to join the types:

```
type WritePost = { title: string, description: string };
type ReadPost = WritePost & { id: number, createdAt: Date };
```

If you have many models that all need the id and createdAt Field you could also create a own type for that db meta information:

```
type DBModelMeta = { id: number; createdAt: Date };
type WritePost = { title: string; description: string };
type ReadPost = WritePost & DBModelMeta;
```

Another solution would be to make the id and createdAt Field optional:

```
type Post = { id?: number; createdAt?: Date; title: string; description: string };
```

However, with this solution you can not be sure if the id / createdAt fields are set if you only have the model and you dont know where the data comes from (e.g. it was read from the database or provided by the user).